# Connect to remote oracle database using odac

Tags: c#, oracle

I need to make asmx web service. I installed ODAC from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html)

Then, i add references to my project:
1) Oracle.DataAccess
2) Oracle.Web

```
[WebMethod]
public string EaaTest(string r_object_id)
{
    string connString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" +
        "(HOST=my host)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=dcmt)));" +
        "User Id=my id ;Password=my password;"

    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connString))
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = string.Format("select DSS_TITLE_RU from DBREP36.DDT_DA_DIRECTION_S where R_OBJECT_ID=0", r_object_id);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        string result = dr.GetString(0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, i have exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Oracle.DataAccess.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Connection must be open for this operation

```
On line: OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Just do what the message says. Open the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message isn't clear *at all*?

> Connection must be open for this operation

You need to open your connection before you execute your command.

```
conn.Open();
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Use `using` statement to dispose your command and reader as you did for your connection.

By the way, you didn't specify zero index in your `string.Format`. Your

```
where R_OBJECT_ID=0
```

should be

```
where R_OBJECT_ID = {0}
```

As a better option, use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). Any kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Since you return just first column of the first row, use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead which is *exactly* what this for.

```
using(var conn = new OracleConnection(connString))
using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"select DSS_TITLE_RU from DBREP36.DDT_DA_DIRECTION_S
                        where R_OBJECT_ID = @id";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@id, r_object_id);
    conn.Open();
    return (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! But i have new exception: ORA-1017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Comment: @Gani Double check your username and password information of your database.

Comment: My Oracle.DataAccess.dll version is 11. My remote database version is 10.2.0. I found many topics about this exception, but it's didn't help me.